# jquery animate method with arrow function not executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-animate

I have an animate method with an arrow function which is not getting executed for some reason, while using angular class property like: `this.innerWidth` which gets device width. Thank you.

```
  $(".window").animate(() => {

     if (this.screenWidth >= 1281) {
       console.log(this.screenWidth);
        }
     else if (this.screenWidth >= 1025 && this.screenWidth <= 1280) {
      console.log(this.screenWidth);  
        }    
     },
      5000,
      "swing",
       () => {
        //call back function
     }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are missing to close one curly braces for "else if" condition
this the valid code

```
$(".window").animate(() => {

 if (this.screenWidth >= 1281) {
   console.log(this.screenWidth);
  }
 else if (this.screenWidth >= 1025 && this.screenWidth <= 1280) {
  console.log(this.screenWidth);      
 }
},
  5000,
  "swing",
   () => {
    //call back function
 }
);
```

Comment: i checked..closeing bracket is not the exact problem..its still not working

Comment: can you add html of that? so we can have better idea

Answer (score 0):

[animate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp) function accepts below arguments

`(selector).animate({styles},speed,easing,callback)`

As per the above syntax your code should be:

```
$(".window").animate({}, 5000, "swing", () => {
        if (this.screenWidth >= 1281) {
            console.log(this.screenWidth);
        } else if(this.screenWidth >= 1025 && this.screenWidth <= 1280) {
            console.log(this.screenWidth);      
        }
    });
```